# remove role once un react Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

My code:

```
async def on_raw_reaction_remove(payload):
  guild=bot.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
  member=bot.get_user(payload.user_id)
  print(payload.emoji)
  if str(payload.emoji)== "<:DragonDragoon:832860714078961714>":
    if payload.message_id == 853930257740070933:
      if payload.channel_id == 853813716541505576:
        Role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Knights")
        await member.remove_roles(Role)
```

I can't find any error on code, yet got error message

```
Ignoring exception in on_raw_reaction_remove
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 142, in on_raw_reaction_remove
    await member.remove_roles(Role)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'remove_roles'
```

The line `member=bot.get_user(payload.user_id)` should get the member, but it is a nonetype? I am sure it is me who reacted, and in a guild

Comment: Might be an issue with intents, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64561309/why-can-i-get-some-users-with-the-bot-get-user-function-but-not-others-discord

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can I get some users with the bot.get\_user function but not others? \[Discord.py\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64561309/why-can-i-get-some-users-with-the-bot-get-user-function-but-not-others-discord)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to run into two problems:

1. `bot.get_user()` return `None` on a valid id. Maybe check the bot intents as pointed out in the comments. This could possibly also be a cache-issue.
2. `bot.get_user()` returns `discord.User` **not** `discord.Member`. You can't remove a role of a user, but only of a member. You will need to use [`guild.get_member(memberid)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Guild.get_member) instead.

---

```py
async def on_raw_reaction_remove(payload):
    guild = bot.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
    member = guild.get_member(payload.user_id)
```

---

If you've disabled the cache you will need to [fetch](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Guild.fetch_member) the member instead

```py
async def on_raw_reaction_remove(payload):
    guild = bot.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
    member = await guild.fetch_member(payload.user_id)
```

Comment: Thanks that solved my problem perfectly

Comment: Also how to enable cache and what is the difference of discord.User and discord.Member?

Comment: Cache settings can be set by constructing your [client object](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#client) with the [`member_cache_flags`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.MemberCacheFlags) parameter. 
`discord.User` is just a user, not associated with a guild. But `discord.Member` however has to be - by definition - member of  a guild. These objects are treaded differently, because you can do different things with them. Have a look at the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html) for more detail!